# How to integrate smart contracts with android app using web3j

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3j, android

I want to integrate smart contracts with the android app. I wrote a simple smart contract and I want to call that smart contract from android app. For example, in UI part of Android, I put one Edittext and one button. So whenever the user clicks the button then the functions of the smart contract executed. How to connect smart contract with android using web3j.

Comment: There is an example in the we3j gibhub web site https://github.com/web3j/sample-project-gradle

Comment: @Jaime HII.Can we deploy the smart contracts from android app?